# Can someone please tell me what game is this? (Red sports car with "kalipa" brand stickers outrunning an explosion)

Tags: game-identification

Please tell me what game the image below represents?  I'm looking for the name of this game and I am unable to identify this game looking at this single image that I have.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It's a promotional image for **[Split/Second](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split/Second)**, "*an arcade racing video game developed by Black Rock Studio and published by Disney Interactive Studios for Microsoft Windows, PlayStation 3, and Xbox 360*", released in 2010.

The image is featured in [this article on the Split/Second game](https://www.timeextension.com/features/the-making-of-splitsecond-the-game-that-tried-to-better-burnout).

Here are two more promotional images, featuring the same car model:

| [image: promotional image for the game] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

And here's a screenshot:

[image]

---

**However!**
My initial reverse image search showed a lot of pictures, of which many were tagged with *Split/Second*. But trying to corroborate this with the 'Kalipa' brand for racing brakes—which is likely completely fictional as it doesn't give any Google hits—I see your particular image (or very similar ones) showing up as a placeholder image or generic gaming representation on gaming-specific hardware (e.g. [this racing game steering wheel](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002790812652.html), [this smart phone](https://doogeemall.com/products/doogee-n40-pro), [this gaming notebook](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Lenovo-Legion-Y540-Gaming-Notebook-15-6-144Hz-FHD-Display-Intel-Core-i7-9750H-Upto-4-5GHz-16GB-RAM-256GB-NVMe-SSD-1TB-HDD-NVIDIA-GeForce-RTX-2060-HDM/854284430), as generic wallpapers (e.g. [this one](https://www.wallpaperg.com/16/bikes-and-cars/3807/cars-wallpapers/14975/kalipa.shtml)), and even as a promotional image for [a completely different Android game](https://apkpure.com/tr/racing-limits-traffic-pro-drif/com.smartapps.HighwayRaceChallenger).

The image pops up when searching for both "[Split/Second](https://www.google.com/search?q=split%2Fsecond)" and "[Kalipa racing breaks](https://www.google.com/search?q=kalipa%20racing%20brakes)", yet combining the two gives [no relevant results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22split%2Fsecond%22%20%22kalipa%22). Moreover, glancing through gameplay and screenshots, I don't see the Kalipa logo anywhere in-game.

I think what happened here is that the image was initially completely unrelated, or maybe made as fan-art (for the game or for the genre), but that the visual similarity lead to confusion, and then to equation.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you for the quick response.  This will help me to pick up this game.  Appreciated.

Comment: @RiaazSuliman No problem. Be sure to upvote and/or accept this answer if it helped you :)